# How to "hook" Notification object

Tags: javascript

I need to "hook" Notification object. I want to every

`new Notification(title);`

log to console title but also create Notification. I want to keep Notification object's values (for example if before Notification requested permission then keep this permission)

How to do this?

Comment: Why? Are you debugging something or creating an audit log? If you are debugging, use breakpoints. If you are collecting logs, add it to the constructor

Comment: This is part of Chrome Extension. I want to log every notification from page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could override the default constructor:

```
// Override default notification constructor:
Notification = (function(Notification) {
  function MyNotification(...args) {
    console.log(...args);
    return new Notification(...args);
  };
  Object.assign(MyNotification, Notification);
  MyNotification.prototype = Notification.prototype;
  return MyNotification;
})(Notification);
```